# clicking on the card call the another API products next to the clicked products in angular 6

Tags: angular

By On-init I am displaying the 1st div, next by click on the 1st div card the 2nd div cards should display in the position index+1, like whichever card is clicked on the 1st div display the 2nd div cards on next to the Clicked cards.how to do it?

app.component.html

```
1st div
<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let x of list; let i = index " style="padding:15px;">
    <div class="card ">
      <div class="card-body ">
       <img src="{{x.productImage}}" class=" rounded" (click)="display(i)" >
       <div>{{x.product_name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
/*2nd div*/
<div class="row ">
  <div class=" col-md-3" *ngFor="let y of similar; let i = index " style="padding:15px;">
    <div class="card ">
     <div class="card-body " >
       <img src="{{y.productImage}}" class=" rounded"  >
       <div>{{y.product_name}}</div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
 list: any;
 similar: any;

 ngOninit {
    this.data.getList().subscribe(data => {
       this.list = data;
    });
 }

 display(x,index) {
    this.data.getSimilar(x.productid).subscribe(data => {
       this.similar = data;
    });
 }
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService { 
    API_URL = 'http://testsite.com/';
    getList() {
      return  this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL +  'getList?page=1&user=10&count=10'  }`);
   }
    getSimilar(prodid) {
      return  this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL +  'getSim?product='+prodid+'&user=10&count=6'  }`);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show the next one in the second div every time you click on one card from the first div? Or the next card for the last clicked one?

Comment: the next card for the last clicked one

Comment: In your **html**, list is an array while it is stated as an object in **ts**. Can you explain? And can you elaborate `getSimilar()` function?

Comment: I am calling from API(j son) and also  I added the service.ts file

Comment: Do you have any parameter in your `getSimilar()` function which indicates on what card you have clicked?

Comment: @Dusan Radovanovic  Yes, edited in code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [by click show the previous cards and clicked card and hide the other index in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53475003/by-click-show-the-previous-cards-and-clicked-card-and-hide-the-other-index-in-an)

Comment: @AIqbalRaj what do you mean by that duplicate of click?

Comment: What is not working here exactly?

Comment: He meant that you asked a question that has been asked before

Comment: by Click which ever I clicked the card next to that clicked card similar products should display

Comment: This should work, check your API if this is not working

Comment: in dialog box it will display no problem but  I want when I click on  2nd card the similar products should display from 3rd card place

Answer (score 0):

Could be way off, but assuming your api service works, the only issue I see is that: Your click event expects product and index, but you're only passing the index.

Why `display(x,index)` when index is never used? and in doing `(click)="display(i)` you aren't even passing the object. It should be `(click)="display(x)` then `display(x){}`